# search to return list of nodes ip in specific format in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I need to do a search in a chef recipe that returns the IP's of all nodes in this specific format

```
'IP','IP',etc
```

so far by searching I've come up with this but the output is not exactly in the format that I want and I don't know how to change it.

```
ip = Array.new

search(:node, "name:chef-node*") do |n|
  n["network"]["interfaces"]["eth1"]["addresses"].each_pair do |address,value|
    ip << address if value.has_key?("broadcast")
  end if n["network"]["interfaces"]["eth1"]
end
```

the output is like this:

```
["10.22.33.33", "10.22.33.38", "10.21.33.24"]
```

and I need it like this:

```
'10.210.39.231','10.209.161.18','10.210.66.240'
```

How would I achieve that?

Comment: How are you using/outputting the `ip` variable? The relevant part seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ip = ["10.22.33.33", "10.22.33.38", "10.21.33.24"]

ip.map { |x| "'#{x}'" }.join(',')
# => "'10.22.33.33','10.22.33.38','10.21.33.24'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a nice [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html) or IPs. Just use method [join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join) over it.

```
ip = ["10.22.33.33", "10.22.33.38", "10.21.33.24"]

ip.join(",")
```